# VFR-Reader Crashing in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ios8, vfr-reader

I tested an app that is currently working with the VFR-Reader-Core on iOS8 and I get a complete crash when I try to open a PDF from it. Am I the only one with this problem? any idea of where I can search to correct this? [Here is the crash report](https://gist.github.com/Morialkar/ccd04422dd9253e3b03c)

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In iOS 8, Te file system layout of app containers has changed. Applications and their content are no longer stored in one root directory.

From the iOS 8 Release Notes:

> The file system layout of app containers has changed on disk. Rather
>   than relying on hard-coded directory structure, use the
>   [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) function or the
>   [`URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:) method of the
>   [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFileManager) class. See [Accessing Files and Directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3) in [File
>   System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672).

I've had a brief look into the issue and i can see that VFRReader does not follow the above recommendations from Apple.

I was going to rase an issue on the Github page however issue tracking seems to have been disabled. If i get some extra time today, I will look into resolving this and raising a pull request.

**Edit:** Check out my fork for a version that works on iOS8: https://github.com/liamnichols/Reader
I've also submitted a pull request on the original repo: https://github.com/vfr/Reader/pull/54

Comment: Hi @liamnichols thanks for this fix. But, every time I open a pdf file it crashes on CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, thePDFPageRef); I have tried different pdf files. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Core Graphics and PDF rendering, this is why i rely on third party libraries :) Good luck fixing it though.. Seen some other people ask about that crash on my pull request as well... Maybe they fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

From the ReaderDocument.m of vfreader, the author stated that

> "As well, //  since as of iOS 8, the application's ~/Documents
>   directory no longer lives in //   its bundle, any bundled PDF files must
>   be copied into the the application's //   ~/Documents directory before
>   they can be accessed."

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Finally stumped on this:

```
@synchronized(nil)  {
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef);
}
```

and it's works now in iOS8.

EDIT: did some changes in the code and now even this does not help me avoid this crash. But now if I run on device then it works. (crash on simulator).

Memory leaks, sometimes the good way, sometimes the wrong way :D

Comment: Why not use @synchronized(self) ?